# Loading external HTML into a hybrid web app

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I have a jQuery Mobile web app that is to be submitted to Apple AppStore. I need to load HTML from an external location. This is my setup:

- the app's pages (html, js, css) are packaged in the submitted app, so they will reside locally on the phone
- some of the local pages should have HTML that is generated server-side (PHP). I want to fetch these with AJAX and insert into the DOM. I can't do that with jQuery load() or get() because that would make a cross-domain request. I am doing some AJAX/JSONP calls that run successfully ("web services returning data").

Is there anything stopping me from making a server-side script that puts HTML code inside the response of the JSONP calls? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to think about this if you are going to find a best approach.

First, you are correct, JSONP is only available solution for you. Now everything depends on a content you are going to load.

#### Solution 1

You can load only basic data and use jQuery Mobile to create a page content. This is a standard way. Usually you will not have that much content and jQM can build it very fast, fast enough to even style it before page is ready to be shown.

Modern mobile browsers are fast enough and you will not have any problems with this solution.

#### Solution 2

Another solution requires page content to be created fully on a server side and you will use JSONP only to load that data. This is a bad approach, while you save your mobile phone from data processing you will burden your data connection. No matter where you live current mobile data connections are prone to lag and speed variations. And you don't your page content to be show after the page has been loaded. Not to mention, even if you choose this way jQM still needs to enhance new page markup and that process is much more demanding then dynamic page content creation.

There's another problem in this solution. You need to be very careful with this approach because sometimes your server side generated content will brake JSONP structure.

#### Conclusion

To make story short unless you have some special reason to choose **Solution 2**, always stick with **Solution 1**.